# Adding a link on Quick Launch with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csom, navigation, pnp-powershell

I have a PowerShell script that creates an Office 365 group and configures the associated SharePoint site. During the creation process it tries to add a link on the site's quick launch using the following code

```
$ctx = Get-PnPContext;
$finalizeLinkAdded = $false;
try {
    $web = $ctx.Web
    $navColl = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
    $ctx.Load($navColl) ;       
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    $newNavNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
    $newNavNode.Title = "Link Title"
    $newNavNode.Url = $link
    $newNavNode.AsLastNode = $true

    $navColl.Add($newNavNode) | out-null;

    $web.Update();
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    $finalizeLinkAdded = $true;
}
catch {
    write-host "$((get-date).toString()) Error adding navigation link $($_.toString())";
}
```

This works well when I'm runnig the script from a PowerShell console.  However, this script is run by creating a job

```
$job = Start-Job -InitializationScript { d:\powershell\engagements\assemblies.ps1}  
  -ScriptBlock { d:\powershell\create-group.ps1  }
```

When I do it this way, I get this strange error.

```
Cannot convert argument "parameters", with value: 
"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation", for "Add" to type 
"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation": 
"Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation" 
value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation" to 
type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation"."
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work when the script is run within a start-job scriptblock. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of why do you have error but i would like to suggest you an alternative that i have been using. Since i already see you using PnPContext you should use Add-PnPNavigationNode try adding below syntax and adjust as per your need. for more information refer to [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/addpnpnavigationnode?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
$w = Get-PnPWeb
$lurl = $w.Url + "/Lists/Contactpersonen"
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "Contactpersonen" -Location "QuickLaunch" -Web $w -Url $lurl
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that cmdlet existed. That worked.